# How to count number of primes in a range?

Tags: excel, vba, function, for-loop

I created a `VBA` function called `prime(n)` that outputs `TRUE` if n is a prime number or `FALSE` if not. It works.

```vb
Function prime(n As Integer) As Boolean
    'Place your code here
    Dim i As Integer
    prime = True

    If n = 1 Then
        prime = False
    ElseIf n > 2 Then
        For i = 2 To n - 1
            If n Mod i = 0 Then
                prime = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

I've the task to create a VBA function called `counterprime(n1,n2)` that counts the number of prime numbers between the integers `n1` and `n2` (inclusive). This function is based on the first function and according to the task I can implement a loop and a counter variable as follows:

```vb
For i = n1 to n2
    If prime(i) Then c = c + 1
Next i
```

How should I include this in my `prime(n)` function to create `coutnerprime(n1,n2)`.

Comment: Your new function must contain a loop, `For n1 To n2`, calling function `prime` in each loop and returning the number of `True` returned from these calls.

Comment: You already have the logic.  Just put the loop/counter into a separate function with this signature `Function counterprime(n1 As Integer, n2 As Integer) As Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Function prime(n) As Boolean

Dim i As Long

If n = 1 Or n = 2 Or n = 3 Then
    prime = True
    Exit Function
End If
   
If n < 1 Or n <> CLng(n) Then
    prime = False
    Exit Function
End If
   
For i = 2 To CLng(Sqr(n)) Step 1
   If n Mod i = 0 Then
         prime = False
         Exit Function
   End If
Next i

prime = True

End Function

Function countprime(n1 As Integer, n2 As Integer) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
For i = n1 To n2
   countprime = countprime - prime(i)
Next i

End Function
```